# Delete Max Sum of N Consecutive Numbers in Python?

Tags: python, list, sum

The purpose of this exercise is to delete a set of N numbers from a list which sum is the highest. The exercise is fairly simple but I am struggling with it. So it would be to convert:

```
list = [1, 4, 8, 2, 5]
N = 3
```

To

```
solved_list = [1, 4]
```

In this case, the the highest sum for N (3 numbers) is 8 + 5 + 2. Therefore, it is deleted from the list. This is what I have done so far:

```
def deletehighestsum(lst, n):
    current_max_numbers = lst[0:n]
    current_max = sum(lst[0:n])
    new_max = 0
    new_max_numbers = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        new_max = sum(lst[i:n+i])
        if current_max < new_max:
            new_max_numbers = lst[i:n+i]
    
    solved_list = [x for x in lst if x not in new_max_numbers]
    return solved_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` on `range` with a custom key (sum of slices) to get the starting index of the max key, then slice:

```
l = [1, 4, 8, 2, 5]
N = 3

idx_max = max(range(0, len(l)-N+1), key=lambda x: sum(l[x:x+3]))
# 2

out = l[:idx_max]+l[idx_max+N:]
```

output: `[1, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
l = [1,4,8,2,5]
n = 3
def deletehighestsum(arr,n):
    t = max({x:sum(x) for x in list(combinations(arr,n))})
    l = [i for i in arr if i not in t]
    return l
print(deletehighestsum(l,n))
```

what this solution does is basically checks for all the possible combinations of n integers within the list and then creates a dictionary with the tuple of possible integers as the key and their sum as the value and then checks for the tuple with the maximum sum
after that it creates a list which does not have the integers from the tuple and returns it
*hope this helps*